# Get Link Description in Variant

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.9
I have a rendering variant that uses a plain old General Link.
I can render the Link including description, but I need the link description on a different place in my variant, I did not find something ootb, all I have seen is that I could create a custom token, for example $teaserlinkdescription.
Is this possible without a token, am I missing something?

If someone is interested, this is the current code. Only drawback is that this will just work for a single field, if the Teaser has two Link Fields this code is useless:

```
    public class ResolveTeaserLinkDescription : ResolveVariantTokensProcessor
{
    static readonly ID TeaserLinkId = new ID("FE713FFA-8D9F-6275-813D-06DD7A5EABAA");
    public override string Token
    {
        get
        {
            return "$teaserlinkdescription";
        }
    }

    public override void ResolveToken(ResolveVariantTokensArgs args)
    {
        LinkField linkField = this.GetLinkField(args.ContextItem);
        string resultText = linkField?.Text;

        if (resultText != string.Empty)
        {
            if (args.ResultControl != null)
                args.ResultControl.Controls.Add((Control)new LiteralControl()
                {
                    Text = resultText
                });
            else
                args.Result = resultText;
        }
    }

    private LinkField GetLinkField(Item item)
    {
        return (LinkField)item.Fields[TeaserLinkId];
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same requirement and I didn't find another solution. I've implemented a custom token.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich thank you. Is your solution more generic? I only found a way to create this token but it will work just on one specific link field.

Comment: I've mistaken. I've used NVelocity template instead of custom tokens. Please find my answer below. It is generic enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement not so far ago. After googling, I found only one solution and it was to implement custom NVelocity template:

```
 public class GeneralLinkTool
    {
        public static string GetLinkDescription(Item item, string fieldName = null)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
                {
                    var field = item.Fields[fieldName];
                    if (field != null && field.Type == "General Link")
                    {
                        Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField link = field;
                        value = link.Text;
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Then you need to register the template:

```
public class AddTemplateRenderers : IGetTemplateRenderersPipelineProcessor
    {
        public void Process(GetTemplateRenderersPipelineArgs args)
        {
            args.Context.Put("fieldTokens", new GeneralLinkTool());
        }
    }
```

and:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getVelocityTemplateRenderers>
        <processor type="YourNamespace.AddTemplateRenderers, YourNamespace"
                   patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVelocityTemplateRenderers.GetVelocityTemplateRenderers, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions']"  />
      </getVelocityTemplateRenderers>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now you can use it by adding the Template variant:

[image: template variant]

The following line will return you a link description:

`$fieldTokens.GetLinkDescription($item, "fieldName")`

[image: template variant usage]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you